# Eclipse not able to find libraries after reinstall

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, ide, reinstall

I had to reinstall my OS and now I can't load my old projects on Eclipse IDE. At first it didn't find the GAE source folder, as it was not on the same location where it was when I created the project, so I just changued the variable $GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE to where it really was.

But now it seems that on the new version of the GAE source the library folders have different names, and Eclipse won't find them.

How can I make Eclipse modify the info on my old projects so it updates the library folders names?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Won't setting up the correct Google Library path in Eclipse in Window->Preferences->Google->App Engine help?

Comment: Not for the old projects, their paths remain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python, you need to set the correct paths on Project -> Properties -> External Libraries or edit the .pydevproject file. I did it a few days ago, just replace the ones that can't be found with the ones below.

```
<pydev_project>
....
<pydev_variables_property name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_VARIABLE_SUBSTITUTION">
<key>GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE</key>
<value>/usr/Local/google_appengine</value>
</pydev_variables_property>
<pydev_pathproperty name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_EXTERNAL_SOURCE_PATH">
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/antlr3</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/enum</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/fancy_urllib</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/google-api-python-client</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/graphy</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/grizzled</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/httplib2</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/ipaddr</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/oauth2</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/prettytable</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/protorpc</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/python-gflags/tests</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/simplejson</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/sqlcmd</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/yaml/lib</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/django-1.4</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/webapp2-2.5.2</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/markupsafe-0.15</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/jinja2-2.6</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}/lib/webob-1.1.1</path>
<path>${GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE}</path>
</pydev_pathproperty>
</pydev_project>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! I actually have already tried it, but it continued failing because I didn't remove the wrong paths, thanks for the hint :-)